# Cauchy principal value of two integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate $P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx$ and $P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x(x-i)}dx$

I stat by using the definiton to calculate the first one: $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(\int_{-\frac{1}{\epsilon}}^{-\epsilon}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}\frac{e^{ix}}{x}dx)$

We have a simple pole at $x=0$ therefore the residue is $1$ but how does this helps me?

For the seonc cauchy principal value I have no idea since $f(x)$ is irritating me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the first integral.  To avoid the singularity at the origin, we typically work in the complex plane and deform the integration contour.  To wit, consider the contour integral,

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{i z}}{z}$$

where $C$ is a semicircle of radius $R$ in the upper half-plane, with a small semicircular detour of radius $\epsilon$ at the origin into the upper half plane.  The integral is thus

$$\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} dx \frac{e^{i x}}{x} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{i \epsilon e^{i \phi}}}{\epsilon e^{i \phi}} \\ + \int_{\epsilon}^{R} dx \frac{e^{i x}}{x} + i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{i R e^{i \theta}}}{R e^{i \theta}}$$

Note that the first and third integrals combine to form the Cauchy PV.  The fourth integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$ because its magnitude is bounded by

$$2 \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \lt 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{R}$$

The second integral is, as $\epsilon \to 0$,

$$i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac1{\epsilon e^{i \phi}} = -i \pi$$

By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero as we excluded all poles from inside the contour.  Thus,

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{i x}}{x} = i \pi$$

For the second integral, assume that $|f(z)|$ is at most $O(1)$ as $|z| \to \infty$.  We perform similar steps as above, except this time, there is a pole at $z=i$.  The residue of this pole there is $-i f(i)$, as the pole is simple.  Thus,

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{f(x)}{x (x-i)} - i \pi (i f(0)) = i 2 \pi (-i f(i))$$

or

$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{f(x)}{x (x-i)} = 2 \pi f(i) - \pi f(0)$$